# Arrows in Feynman diagram

Tags: feynman, tikz-feynman

I made Feynman diagram this diagram

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots,wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikZ-feynman,contour}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[14]{R}{0.577\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
\begin{feynman}[small]
\vertex (i1)  [particle=\(e^{-}\)];    
\vertex (start) at (-0.3,-0.2) {\(e^{-}\)};
\vertex [above right=20pt of i1] (ii1);
\vertex [above right=20pt of ii1] (v1);

\vertex [above left=20pt of v1] (ii2);
\vertex [above left=20pt of ii2] (i2) {\(e^{-}\)};

\vertex [right=40pt of v1] (v2);

\vertex [above right= 10pt and 17pt of v1]  {\(q\)};
\vertex [below right= 5pt and 17pt of v1]  {\(\gamma\)};

\vertex [above left = 8pt and -1pt of v1] {\(k'\)};
\vertex [below left = 8pt and -1pt of v1]  {\(k\)};

\vertex [above left= 23pt and 13pt of v1]  {\(p'\)};
\vertex [below left= 23pt and 13pt of v1]  {\(p\)};

\vertex [below right=20pt of v2] (ff1);
\vertex [below right=20pt of ff1] (f1);
\vertex [above right=20pt of v2] (ff2);
\vertex [above right=20pt of ff2] (f2);

\diagram {
(i1) -- [fermion] (ii1)-- [fermion] (v1),
(ii1)-- [boson, momentum, half left, blue] (ii2),
(v1) -- [fermion] (ii2)-- [fermion] (i2),
(v2) -- [boson, momentum',blue] (v1),
(f1) -- [fermion,very thick] (v2)-- [fermion, very thick] (f2),
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

but the momentum arrow in the left is too big. How can I change its length?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The momentum arrow should be, by default, 70% of the length of the initial path.  This can change quite significantly if the path is quite curved, as it is here, but you can always rectify it with the `arrow shorten` key.

In particular, the `momentum` style allows for optional arguments as follows:

```
momentum={[<optional momentum styles>]<momentum label>}
```

I also noticed that you are manually placing labels to look like they are on the edge of certain propagators.  You can actually automatically do this with `edge label`.

Here's the diagram with the momentum arrow shortened, and using `edge label` instead of manually placing nodes along edges:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
  \begin{feynman}[small]
    \vertex (i1)  [particle=\(e^{-}\)];
    \vertex (start) at (-0.3,-0.2) {\(e^{-}\)};
    \vertex [above right=20pt of i1] (ii1);
    \vertex [above right=20pt of ii1] (v1);

    \vertex [above left=20pt of v1] (ii2);
    \vertex [above left=20pt of ii2] (i2) {\(e^{-}\)};

    \vertex [right=40pt of v1] (v2);

    \vertex [below right=20pt of v2] (ff1);
    \vertex [below right=20pt of ff1] (f1);
    \vertex [above right=20pt of v2] (ff2);
    \vertex [above right=20pt of ff2] (f2);

    \diagram* {
      (i1) -- [fermion, edge label'=\(p\)] (ii1)
           -- [fermion, edge label'=\(k\)] (v1),
      (ii1)-- [
               boson,
               momentum={[arrow shorten=0.25, arrow style=blue]},
               half left,
               blue] (ii2),
      (v1) -- [fermion, edge label'=\(k'\)] (ii2)
           -- [fermion, edge label'=\(p'\)] (i2),
      (v2) -- [boson, blue, momentum'={[arrow style=blue]\(q\)}, edge label=\(\gamma\)] (v1),
      (f1) -- [fermion,very thick] (v2)
           -- [fermion, very thick] (f2),
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: And if i want the edge label to be black instead of blue?

Comment: @JonSnow I see you've asked many questions here, but have not accepted any answer to any of your question.  People volunteer their own time and effort answering other people's question; none of us are paid.  The least you can do is use the tickmark ✓ to accept an answer as a sign of thanks, otherwise some people might be very reluctant to answer you in the future.  Regarding your particular question, I'll just refer you to the [pgf manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), and have a look at `edge node`.

Comment: I am so sorry, I didn't know about the tickmark.
And thanks for the manual reference.

Comment: No worries, though don't forget all the other questions you asked before too :)  To give you a more definite answer, you can make the *γ* edge label black with: `edge node={node[auto, black]{\(\gamma\)}}`.